# Resolve docker windows container name from host

Tags: docker, dns, windows-container

I'm trying to resolve a docker container address from the host.  Windows host.  Windows container.  I've reviewed number of similar questions:

[How do I resolve hostnames to Docker containers from the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185111/how-do-i-resolve-hostnames-to-docker-containers-from-the-host)

[Docker 1.10 access a container by it's hostname from a host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828487/docker-1-10-access-a-container-by-its-hostname-from-a-host-machine)

[Docker - Windows Container Not Resolving Hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885539/docker-windows-container-not-resolving-hosts)

None of these questions address this specific question.  Seems like a trivial operation and I simply don't understand why it doesn't work.

So for example

```
$ docker network create -d nat --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 test-net
$ docker container run  --network test-net --name example-1 test/example1
```

Where test/example1 is simply an asp.net core web server.

So it seems to me I should be able to resolve the container name from the host based on the various clues I see in the above referenced answers. For example

```
$ nslookup example-1 172.25.0.1
$ nslookup example-1 127.0.0.11
$ nslookup example-1.test-net.docker 127.0.0.11
```

However nothing works.

Naturally I don't need this capability for production, but it would be very helpful for testing.  I simply don't understand why I can't get this to work.  What am I missing?